# How can I write a function that accepts a std::vector of Eigen matrices of different size?

Tags: c++, stdvector, eigen

I would like to write a function like:

```
void do_sth(const std::vector<Eigen::Matrix2d> >&); //http://eigen.tuxfamily.org
```

but it should work for different Matrix sizes, e.g. Matrix4d.

I could not figure it out even after reading this:
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html

Could someone please help ?

Comment: While `Eigen::Ref` can be used as linked in the example, in your case a `std::vector<Eigen::Matrix>` cannot be passed to a function that uses `std::vector<Eigen::Ref>`.  The issue is the `vector`, not the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use something like:

```
template <std::size_t W, std::size_t H>
void do_sth(const std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, W, H>>&);
```

Comment: ok, this works. thank you. however I am still hoping to get a non-templated solution, e.g. by using the Eigen::Ref class (?). If nothing else comes up I will accept your answer.

Comment: for example I can not separate the functions definition from its declaration in implementation and header file the usual way (I know there are workarounds but I rather not use templates, because the problem described seems simple enough to avoid them (even though I do not know how ;) ))

Comment: @user1304680 Implement using templates and move template bodies into compilation unit with explicit instantiation.  Much cleaner than relying on Ref magic (which might incur unexpected copies)